# Sass: errno::enoent: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, sass

I know this is a terribly bland error to be running into, but I'm encountering a regular "file not found" error in Sass 3.4.2:

```
/*
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - dumdum.scss

Backtrace:
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.12/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:482:in `read'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.12/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:482:in `update_stylesheet'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.12/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:215:in `block in update_stylesheets'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.12/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:209:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.12/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:209:in `update_stylesheets'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.12/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:293:in `watch'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.12/lib/sass/plugin.rb:108:in `method_missing'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.12/lib/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb:381:in `watch_or_update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.12/lib/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb:51:in `process_result'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.12/lib/sass/exec/base.rb:52:in `parse'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.12/lib/sass/exec/base.rb:19:in `parse!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.12/bin/sass:13:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/sass:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/sass:23:in `<main>'
*/
```

I've run into this before, but I've had no luck in diagnosing/solving it. It also shows up as a weird element in the page its linked to.

Could someone help me understand the traceback? I'm sure it's something incredibly simple, but I know very little Ruby. I've tried removing/reinstalling Sass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced a similar error in my project, deleting the sass-cache directory at the root of my project, then run sass/grunt again solved the problem for me...

```
rm .sass-cache/ -R
```

Hop this helps

Comment: That makes a.. ton of sense. I completely forgot that Sass caches files at in the directory where the commands are run, not the directory where the stylesheets are stored. I'll have to give this a shot next time I run into the error.

Answer (score 2):

Whether Ruby or Rails (too), your backtrace means that an error is rising from the gem's code itself. If you were to open those files and follow the backtrace, you could see how the sass gem works.

**EDIT**: If you have manually un/installed a gem, it is best to run `bundle install` so you correctly match the specs in your `Gemfile.lock`. If such a file sounds new to you, I highly suggest reading http://bundler.io/ , a gem manager letting you control which gems/versions are required for your app!

**NOTE**: If you are working with Rails, the rest of my answer below may help. (Given from personal experience I've had a couple months ago.)

This error means that you do not have the file `dumdum.scss` in your directory, most likely `app/assets/stylesheets/`. I suggest doing a quick `grep` search for where you use `dumdum`. For example, in the app I am working on, I have a file `_colors.scss`, and it is referenced in and overrides stylesheet (for bootstrap) as `@import "colors";`.

Comment: Bizarre–all the files were in the right places. There are `sass` and `css` subdirs with all the partials and master files to import in `app/client/stylesheets` and I was using `sass --watch sass:css` from that `stylesheets` directory to process. Moved the project to another machine with a fresh install of Sass and it seems to be working fine again.

Comment: I edited my answer with some help, in regards to gems. I hope it helps. It seems your issue lied with having non-pristine versions of the gem lying around. In reply to your comment, [`gem pristine [GEMNAME]`](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-pristine)

Comment: Thanks, onebree. I really only use gems for project styles, but I'll take a look at bundler for package management.

Comment: Did I at help help answer your question? Are you having trouble with your clean install? >> Also, might I add, bundler is for gem dependency management, not general packages. It is especially good since Rails 4 does not use plugins (`vendor/plugins`)

Comment: No, the clean install seems to have addressed the problem. I work primarily with JavaScript/Node packages and really only use Ruby for Sass frameworks. That said, I use several and run into the issue fairly frequently, so anything that might help keep things consistent always sounds good to me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but couldn't resolve it with the solutions aforementioned, but I had to employ a hack and hope approach.

Things I tried before my hack and hope approach:

1. I deleted all the .sass-cache folders which may contain my sass file
2. I uninstalled and reinstalled the sass gem.
3. I upgraded Ruby and Sass. For some reason, I can't uninstall the ruby command prompt cleanly. So I'm still using **ruby 2.3.3p222 and Sass version 3.4.23**

So my **solution** was to use **[sassmeister](http://www.sassmeister.com/)** to convert the scss and that solved my problem. To compress the css file I used **[CSS Compressor](http://www.csscompressor.com)**. This method is effective, if you don't have a clean setup of the ruby/sass install.

1. Next take the compressed css file and save a new CSS file with a new
   filename.
2. Next, go to your html/php files and change the CSS filename to the new CSS filename from step 1, in your .
3. This should do the trick. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error:

*"Sass: errno::enoent: No such file or directory"* 
 By moving the project directory 
 **Sass**

** into **Ruby** folder:

```
PS C:\Ruby26-x64\Sass> sass --watch scss:css
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
>>> Change detected to: scss/style.scss
      write css/style.css
      write css/style.css.map
```